# How can I make my character invisible in GTA V?

Tags: pc, mods, grand-theft-auto-v

I've been looking for a mod or config trick to make the [GTA V](http://www.rockstargames.com/V/info) character invisible (in the offline mode of course). Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Using the [GTA V saves editor](http://x3t-infinity.com/Home.php?ID=2) ghost button is not an option since this is not supported for the PC version.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably stop moving the goalposts of your question.  You're first asking how to make yourself invisible.  Now you're asking how to make yourself invisible with a specific program; that invalidates the existing answer, and generally isn't something we support.

Comment: @Frank I'm sorry. I'm used to do a resume of the matter in the post to reflect the advances in the solution for future searchers with the same problem.

Comment: I get that.  But solutions belong in the *answer*.  Problems with a solution belong in the comments, not as an addendum to the question.

Comment: @Frank I understand. I will edit it and remove the answer related part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank I'm trying to help with the editing to reach the needed reputation to upvote some useful answers I found. I have the reputation in other stack forums, but not here, where I can not even thank them using comments.

Comment: Then make some *useful* edits.  Doing nothing but linking the game's name to the website doesn't improve a single thing.  Your latest one, with adding the version-differences tag, is helpful.  Make some substantial improvements in an edit, please.  There's a reason the six character limit is the minimum, and that's specifically to prevent minor edits.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your feedback, I will try to add more tags, but it's difficult helping there because few tags were created for the users with +300 reputation, and even some game titles have not its own tags. Would be really useful if you could moderate an old deleted question I did. I recently updated it with the required info to be valid.

Comment: If you're referring to your game identification question, I'm afraid there's no longer a question there.  Our policy for those is to leave them closed, if you're adding a picture after the fact.  The exception is primarily to be used for games you run into while watching a TV show or movie.  If you have to hunt down a screenshot, chances are extremely good you're going to find the name along with the screenshot, which is what you've managed to do with yours.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk You can edit the tag wiki's if you want to provide more information instead of linking to the wiki's of games. It's our way of giving a bit of information about the game. If you click on any tag you'll have the option to "improve tag wiki" just click on that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [GTA V save editor](http://x3t-infinity.com/Home.php?ID=2).

Load up your save game into the editor and then click the `Ghost` button to make your character invisible. The Ghost button can be found under the "Character" menu, to the right of the stars, it looks like a pacman ghost.

Save the file and put it where your GTA V saves are. Load the save and then you'll need to switch to any other character that isn't invisible and then back to the invisible character.

Comment: Nice idea, but sadly the icon is not there (I add a screenshot in the question). Maybe is a version issue. I'll investigate it. Thanks for the quick anwser!

Comment: That's strange, in my version it's right next to the tshirt.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk From the Patch notes; 

2.0.0.6 - 12-16-2013
Added...Invisible Mode for Franklin and Trevor (BETA)

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk maybe they removed in later, I couldn't find that they'd removed it in the patch notes, so not sure what's going on, try downloading this older version.

Comment: thanks again for your help! I will upvote your answer/comments as soon I gain the reputation.

Comment: I found the problem. When the editor began to support PC saves, they removed the ghost button since it is only working for PS3 and XBOX360.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to make the character invisible in the PC version using this mod: [Invisibility Cloak 1.1](https://es.gta5-mods.com/scripts/invisibility-cloak)

You still can use the [Aequitas solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230869/103959) in XBOX360 or PS3.